# Error 403 forbidden accesssing Mule Release EE Repository for a licenced account

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I'm trying to modify a Mule API proxy, which i downloaded from Anypoint Platform portal.

When I try to build with maven I get the following error:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project api-gateway-sample-rest-proxy: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mule.examples:api-gateway-sample-rest-proxy:mule-application:3.1.6: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.anypoint:mule-http-proxy-extension:jar:mule-plugin:1.1.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.anypoint:mule-http-proxy-extension:jar:mule-plugin:1.1.4: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.anypoint:api-gateway-extensions-parent:pom:1.1.3 from/to MuleRepository (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/): authorization failed for https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/mulesoft/anypoint/api-gateway-extensions-parent/1.1.3/api-gateway-extensions-parent-1.1.3.pom, status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]

I added the credentials to the Maven settings file as posted in this [guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb).

Note that this error is not an 401 - Unauthorized but a forbidden. The credentials provided are good but I don't am not allowed to access resource.

My account was created under our organization using Anypoint Authentication.
Our license is a Titanium license.

Where can i find the exact requirements to access this resource?

UPDATE

The settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings>
    <servers> 
     <server>
      <id>MuleRepository</id>
      <username>My user name</username>
      <password>some password</password>
    </server>   
   </servers> 
    <pluginGroups> 
        <pluginGroup>org.mule.tools</pluginGroup> 
    </pluginGroups> 
    <profiles> 
        <profile> 
            <id>Mule</id> 
            <activation> 
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> 
            </activation> 
            <repositories> 
                <repository> 
                    <id>MuleRepository</id> 
                    <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name> 
                    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url> 
                    <layout>default</layout> 
                    <releases> 
                        <enabled>true</enabled> 
                    </releases> 
                    <snapshots> 
                        <enabled>true</enabled> 
                    </snapshots> 
                </repository>               
            </repositories> 
    
        </profile> 
    </profiles> 
</settings>
```

The proxy pom.xml file was not changed. Anyway, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.mule.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-sample-rest-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>

    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <name>psh_rtn_webapi-v1-dmz_qua</name>

    <properties>
        <muleHttpConnectorVersion>1.7.2</muleHttpConnectorVersion>
        <muleMavenPluginVersion>3.5.3</muleMavenPluginVersion>
        <proxyExtensionVersion>1.1.4</proxyExtensionVersion>
        <restValidatorVersion>2.2.4</restValidatorVersion>
        <attachMuleSources>true</attachMuleSources>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-proxy-extension</artifactId>
            <version>${proxyExtensionVersion}</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-rest-validator-extension</artifactId>
            <version>${restValidatorVersion}</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>${muleHttpConnectorVersion}</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${muleMavenPluginVersion}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mule</id>
            <name>Mule Public Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>MuleRepository</id>
            <name>Mule Release EE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-plugin-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-plugin-snapshots</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <downloadUrl>http://www.mulesoft.com/mule-esb-enterprise-trial-download</downloadUrl>
        <repository>
            <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
            <name>Mule Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/ci-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>mule-ee-snapshots</id>
            <name>Mule Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/ci-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Which credentials are you using to authenticate in the settings.xml file? Share your configurations and pom, masking confidential information like user and passwords.

Comment: Are you using mule 3 or mule 4?

Comment: I am using Mule 4.

Comment: @MiguelSlv the file is there. Probably there is some problem with your configurations. We can only help if you share them

Comment: @aled I just added the settings file.

Comment: @aled, and now the pom.xml file, just in case you need to check.

Comment: Please make sure that the username / password you used to access Mule's Nexus repository (MuleRepository in your case) are Nexus enterprise credentials (this needs to be asked from Mulesoft support if you are an existing customer).

Comment: To be sure if the credentials are good try opening the link from the error in a browser with those credentials: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/mulesoft/anypoint/api-gateway-extensions-parent/1.1.3/api-gateway-extensions-parent-1.1.3.pom

Comment: @oim, that was it. I was not aware that there wa a nexus account. Thanks very much.

Comment: You are following a very old document which. Refer this [updated one](https://docs.mulesoft.com/exchange/to-publish-assets-maven). The mule ee repo does not have nexus in the URL anymore. Also, try to use connected apps instead of massing an account's username and password